# jQuery Ajax hangs on large file uploads

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am developing an image hosting website that will send an image over to the server via ajax from jQuery.

If I send a large file, for some weird reason the `complete` option takes a while to do anything, yet in Developer Tools for Chrome, the Network tab shows me that the request completed and returns anything it should return (In this case, if an image is >20MB, it'll return "File too large" in json format.)

What is the best method to tell ajax to run through it's reporting process once a request is complete, regardless if the file was too large or failed?

This is the code I have so far:

```
$.ajax({
    xhr: function()
    {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(evt)
        {
            if(evt.lengthComputable)
            {
                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                    percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);

                $('#btn-upload').fadeOut();
                $('.progress-circle').delay(500).fadeIn('fast');
                progressCircle.animate(percentComplete / 100);
            }
        }, false);

        return xhr;
    },
    url: $('form').attr('action'),
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json',
    global: false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    complete: function(jqXHR)
    {
        if(jqXHR.readyState === 4)
        {
            var result = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);

            if(jqXHR.status == 422)
            {
                $('.progress-circle').fadeOut('fast', function()
                {
                    $('.errors p').html(result);
                    $('.errors').delay(500).fadeIn('fast');
                });
            }
            else
            {
                window.location.replace(result.url);
            }
        }
    }
}, 'json');
```

Comment: 1-Make sure can upload file size >20 in php.ini for example it may be post_max_size = 8M change it to your need

Comment: @Azmatkarim I have made sure of this, I set the following values ini php.ini:

`post_max_size = 1000M`
`upload_max_size = 1000M`
`max_uploads = 200`

The file does get processed by the server and it does output any messages, whether it succeeded or failed. It's when the request completes, the javascript just hangs for a minute or two before it displays the message. I want to try and avoid the javascript hanging. Is it possible?

Comment: restarted the web server?

Comment: @Azmatkarim It is restarted and working, the new php.ini values are applied.

Comment: @Azmatkarim This is what happens, basically: https://vgy.me/4CqeUC.png

The request is made, and it completes. The "100%" circle should fade out and then fade in the error message right after that request completes. But it just hangs there for a minute, then it does what it should.

I'm not sure if it's a browser issue, or a javascript issue.

Comment: can you upload small images?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106454/discussion-between-azmat-karim-and-techkat).